# IIS Worker process using 6gb RAM on web server with ASP.NET MVC web site

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, memory-leaks

I have a web site running in its own Application Pool (IIS 8). Settings for the pool are default i.e. recycle every 29 hours.

Our web server only has 8gb RAM and I have noticed that the worker process for this web site regularly climbs to 6gb RAM and slows the server to a crawl. This is the only site currently on the web server.

I also have SQL Express 2016 installed as well. The site is using EF version 6.1.3.

The MVC site is very straightforward. It has a GETPDF controller which finds a row in a table, gets PDF info stored in a field then serves it back to the browser as follows :-

```
using (eBillingEntities db = new eBillingEntities())
{
try
{
    string id = model.id;
    string emailaddress = Server.HtmlEncode(model.EmailAddress).ToLower().Trim();  

    eBillData ebill = db.eBillDatas.ToList<eBillData>().Where(e => e.PURL == id && e.EmailAddress.ToLower().Trim() == emailaddress).FirstOrDefault<eBillData>();

    if (ebill != null)
    {

        // update the 'Lastdownloaded' field.
        ebill.LastDownloaded = DateTime.Now;
        db.eBillDatas.Attach(ebill);
        var entry = db.Entry(ebill);
        entry.Property(en => en.LastDownloaded).IsModified = true; 
        db.SaveChanges();


        // Find out from the config record whether the bill is stored in the table or in the local pdf folder.
        //
        Config cfg = db.Configs.ToList<Config>().Where(c => c.Account == ebill.Account).FirstOrDefault<Config>();

        bool storePDFDataInEBillTable = true;

        if (cfg != null)
        {
            storePDFDataInEBillTable = cfg.StorePDFDataInEBillDataTable;
        }
        // End of Modification

        byte[] file;

        if (storePDFDataInEBillTable)
        {

            file = ebill.PDFData;
        }
        else
        {

            string pathToFile = "";

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cfg.LocalPDFDataFolder))
                pathToFile = cfg.LocalBackupFolder;
            else
                pathToFile = cfg.LocalPDFDataFolder;

            if (!pathToFile.EndsWith(@"\"))
                pathToFile += @"\";

            pathToFile += ebill.PDFFileName;

            file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pathToFile);

        }

        MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();

        output.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
        output.Position = 0;

        HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ebill.pdf");

        return new FileStreamResult(output, "application/pdf");
    }
    else
        return View("PDFNotFound");

}
catch
{
    return View("PDFNotFound");

}
```

Are there any memory leaks here?

Will the file byte array and the memory stream get freed up?

Also, is there anything else I need to do concerning clearing up the entity framework references?

If the code looks OK, where would be a good place to start looking?

Regards

Comment: If I wrap my memory stream in a using statement then I get an error on the  saying "Cannot access a closed Stream" e.g. using( MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())

        output.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
        output.Position = 0;

        HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ebill.pdf");

        return new FileStreamResult(output, "application/pdf");
   } }

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any memory leaks here?

No.

> Will the file byte array and the memory stream get freed up?

Eventually, yes.  But that may be the cause of your excessive memory use.

> Also, is there anything else I need to do concerning clearing up the entity framework references?

No.

> If the code looks OK, where would be a good place to start looking?

If this code is the cause of your high memory use, it's because you are loading files into memory.  And you're loading two copies of each file in memory, once in a byte[] and copying to a MemoryStream.

There's no need to do that.

To eliminate the second copy of the file use the [MemoryStream(byte[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) constructor instead of copying the bytes from the byte[] to an empty MemoryStream.

To eliminate the first copy in memory, you can stream the data into a temporary file that will be the target of your FileStreamResult, or initialize the FileStreamResult using a ADO.NET stream.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sqlclient-streaming-support

If you go to ADO.NET streaming your DbContext, will need to be scoped to your Controller, instead of a local variable, which is a good practice in any case.

Comment: Hi David,  Thanks for the tips. I also ran the SQL profiler and noticed that EF is doing a full select on my ebilldata table (which includes the field containing the PDF data). This could take a while. I don't appear to be doing a select * in my EF code at all so I don't know where this is coming from. Is there a way to stop it loading the PDF data field until I access it?

Comment: EF does not lazy-load properties.  If you want the document loaded separately, it needs to be in a separate entity.  You can use a separate table, or use EF Table Splitting to map EBillData and EBillDocument (or whatever) to a single table.  see eg https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/09/01/splitting-tables.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In addition to David's advice. I noticed that I was doing the following

```
**db.eBillDatas.ToList<eBillData>()**
```

therefore I was getting all the data from the database **then**  fetching it again with the where clause.

I didn't notice the problem until the database started to fill up.

I removed that part and now the IIS worker processing is about 100mb.